# VBA code for C# addins button execution

Tags: excel, ribbon, excel-addins, vba

I have add-ins (developed in C#) with buttons on the ribbon, 
how I can execute a button on the ribbon connected to the add-ins?

The following codes are not working:

```
Application.CommandBars("GuruExcelAddin").Controls("FixIssueBtn").Execute
```

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FixIssueBtn")
```

I want to execute the button from Excel VBA.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description of the problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: the error "invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: may somebody help?